# open, run and close url in background

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using angular and I want to generate a pdf file from another page/route but I do not want to open that page, I want want to press the download pdf button on the page I am at and it downloads a pdf page from another url/page in the background

Comment: Simply set the `download` attribute on the `a` tag (if done programmatically: on the temporary hidden `a` tag you simulate the click on for initiating the blob download, otherwise on the visible link to the PDF, if you have one), then a download will be started instead of opening the PDF in the browser.

Answer (score -1):

You can download with this

```
async onClickDownload(id: number) {
        try {
            const res = await this.service.getPDF(id);
            this.fileDownload(res);
        } catch (e) {
            //you can catch error
        }
    }

    fileDownload(obj) {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(obj);
        window.open(url);
    }
```

HTML:

```
<button click="onClickDownload(5)>Download PDF</button>
```

service:

```
async getPDF(id: number): Promise<any> {
        const resp = await this.httpClient.get(`/api/PDF/${id}/download`, { responseType: 'blob' }).toPromise();
        return resp;
    }
```